# Export a table with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, phpmyadmin, export

I'm not able to find in SQL Server 2005 the utility that phpmyadmin has for exporting tables.

My case is:

I have an small table (20 rows) and I need to delete some columns I won't need.

So I need a way to dump all info the table contains in an insert query. Then, editing this query I just need to delete the columns I don't need and later I can delete the table and create it again filling it with the edited insert query.

How can I do that with SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than exporting, dropping, recreating and repopulating the table, why not simply drop each of the unwanted columns:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN ColumnName;
```

Further details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174123%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).